# How do I add a jar to jconsole classpath in windows?

Tags: java, jvm, classpath, jmx, jconsole

I'm trying to invoke a **JMX MBean** via **Jconsole**, but the method that I'm calling receive an object that needs to be on **jconsole classpath** in order to work.

I've tried this and the jconsole does not open (and no error is shown):

```
jconsole -J-Djava.class.path=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\jconsole.jar;path_to_newjar_\newjar.jar
```

Comment: Try -J-cp -Jpath instead of -J-Djava.class.path=...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still nothing, the jconsole does not open.

Comment: Since the doc suggests your original plan, my comment is unhelpful and I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take jconsole.jar out of the -J classpath. It's already set in the jconsole launcher.

**===== Update =====**

Hmmm.... I take back my suggestion.  I have a windows batch file I use [which works] which adds a JAR to the classpath. The intent is to add the [JMXMP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jmx/overview/connectors.html) JMX client into jconsole and then launch to the argument specified JMX Service URL. It looks like this:

```
@echo off
start /B jconsole -J-Djava.class.path=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\jconsole.jar;MY-JAR-PATH\jmx-optional-1.0-b02-SNAPSHOT.jar service:jmx:jmxmp://localhost:%1
```

If a command like that does not work (i.e. jconsole still will not launch, but does not error out either), then you need to figure out where it is stalling. 2 suggestions for this:

1. Launch another jconsole and attach to the stalled jconsole by PID, switch to the Threads tab and eyeball what's going on in the **main** thread.
2. Or, (since it looks like you're in windows) hit **Ctrl-Break** and hopefully it will print out a thread dump to the console and you can then eyeball the **main** thread going-ons there.

Post back if you get anything  (or if you don't....)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but not yet. Still the command doesn't work. Jconsole is not opened and no error is shown.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, update your answer for the optimal response. It works only with the following : jconsole -J-Djava.class.path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_5
1\lib\jconsole.jar" service:jmx:jmxmp://localhost:%1

Comment: Although my JAVA_HOME is ok, it only worked with the " . I think it's because the spaces between words

Comment: Daaaamn ...... Hate that. I never install **anything** in Program Files for that reason. So it's working as expected ?

Comment: Yes...worked perfectly. This way: jconsole -J-Djava.class.path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17
\lib\jconsole.jar";"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\eventFilteringEJB.jar"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have access to both local & remote processes, the above answers are still missing a step.

From the Java 8 oracle docs:

> If the JMX agent uses a connector which is not included in the Java platform, you need to add the connector classes to the class path when you run the jconsole command, as follows.
>
> `$ jconsole -J-Djava.class.path=JAVA_HOME/lib/jconsole.jar:JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:connector-path`
>
> In the command above, **connector-path** is the directory or the Java archive (Jar) file containing the connector classes that are not included in the JDK, that are to be used by JConsole.

In your case, then, the command would be:

`$ jconsole -J-Djava.class.path=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\jconsole.jar;%JAVA_HOME%/lib/tools.jar:path_to_newjar_\newjar.jar`

When you leave off the `JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar`, local processes are no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in Windows is to use quotes on your classpath, for example:

`jconsole -J-Djava.class.path="%JAVA_HOME%\lib\jconsole.jar;path_to_newjar_\newjar.jar"`